# ENS - Events not returned in the callback URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, transactional-messaging-api, event-notification-service

We configured a callback URL in order to track events related to email sends as click, open, bounce and notsent as explained [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens-activities.htm).
We created a definitionkey as transactional message; at the moment we are facing an issue because even if I open/click the email, the engagement events are not returned to the callback.
Do you ever seen this behavior?
We already checked the callback url and the subscription created between the definitionkey and the callback; it seems to be correct because the callback is verified and it can collect send and bounce events.

Comment: Did you ever find out why ENS are not showing up? I have the same issue even after verifying the call back url and creating the subscription. Let me know thats Matt